# Use Stirling's approximation to evaluate the probability $\lim_{n\to \infty}\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$

Tags: probability, limits

As part of a some probability problem (probability of gettin $n$ heads and $n$ tails in $2n$ trials with a fair coin) I have derived the formula: $$p_n=\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$$

I want to evaluate:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} p_n$$

for $n\in \mathbb N$, using the following bound:

$$e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}<\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}<e^{\frac{1}{12n}}$$

This is a "special" case of [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) from Herbert Robbins that can be found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2308012?origin=crossref). I am stuck because I am not sure if my calculation is correct and the result makes no sense to me. When I calculate the limit I get **zero**. Does this not contradict the law of large numbers? Wouldn't I expect to get a distribution of $50 \%$ heads and $50\%$ tails if I toss a fair coin an infinite amount of times which then should imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n=1$?

**What I have tried so far:**
$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split}\lim_{n\to \infty} p_n&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \binom{2n}{n} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \\[10pt] &=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^24^n} \end{split}\end{equation*}$$

Rewriting the approximation:

$$ \begin{equation*}\begin{split} &\phantom{\iff} \, \, \, \,e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}<\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}<e^{\frac{1}{12n}} \\[10pt] & \iff e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}  \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n < n!<e^{\frac{1}{12n}} \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\end{split}\end{equation*}$$

Replacing $n!$ in $p_n$

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split} &\phantom{iff}\frac{(2n)!}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^2 4^n}<\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 4^n}<\frac{(2n)!}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{12n}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^2 4^n} \\[10pt] &\iff\underbrace{\frac{1}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^2 4^n}}_{:=g(n)}<\underbrace{\frac{1}{(n!)^2 4^n}}_{:=f(n)}<\underbrace{\frac{1}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{12n}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^2 4^n}}_{:=h(n)}\end{split}\end{equation*}$$

From the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem): If $\lim_{n\to \infty} g(n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} h(n)=L$ and $g(n) < f(n) < h(n)$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=L$

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split}\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^2 4^n} \\[10pt] &=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{2}{12n+1}} e^{(-2n)} n^{(2n+1)}4^n} \\[10pt] &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{e^{-\frac{24n}{12n+1}}}{n^{2n+1}4^n}=0\end{split}\end{equation*}$$

Analogous $\lim_{n \to \infty} h(n)=0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty } f(n)=0$. Therefore,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}p_n=0$$

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the answer that $p_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ is correct, but I'll have to think about how to square that with the law of large numbers.

Comment: It does not contradict the law of large numbers.  If you flip a coin two million times, you are very likely to have *nearly* a million heads and a million tails for some reasonable definition of "nearly".  But the probability of a precise split is very small.

Comment: You showed that $f(n)$ tends to $0$. But $p_n$ is $f(n) \times (2n)!$. Why would that tend to zero as well? (It does, but...) There is also something wrong with the way you simplified the exponentials in computing the limit of $g(n)$: $e^a e^b \neq e^{ab}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1756063/589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct estimations are as follows:
$$
\frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!^2 }} \le \frac{{(2n)^{2n} e^{ - 2n} \sqrt {2\pi 2n} e^{\frac{1}{{24n}}} }}{{\left( {n^n e^{ - n} \sqrt {2\pi n} e^{\frac{1}{{12n + 1}}} } \right)^2 }} = \frac{{4^n }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}e^{\frac{1}{{24n}} - \frac{2}{{12n + 1}}} 
$$
and
$$
\frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!^2 }} \ge \frac{{(2n)^{2n} e^{ - 2n} \sqrt {2\pi 2n} e^{\frac{1}{{24n + 1}}} }}{{\left( {n^n e^{ - n} \sqrt {2\pi n} e^{\frac{1}{{12n}}} } \right)^2 }} = \frac{{4^n }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}e^{\frac{1}{{24n + 1}} - \frac{1}{{6n}}} .
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}e^{\frac{1}{{24n + 1}} - \frac{1}{{6n}}}  \le p_n  \le \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}e^{\frac{1}{{24n}} - \frac{2}{{12n + 1}}} .
$$
In particular,
$$
p_n  \sim \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: I was about to respond to your comment. I feel a bit stupid for not realizing that I could have just substituted $n=2n$ into stirlings approximation and use it to simplify/approximate the numerator $(2n)!$ aswell. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$0$ is correct for the limit.

Suppose you flipped a coin $2n$ times.  You are asking for the probability exactly $n$ are heads.

For this binomial distribution, the mean is $n$ and variance is $\frac n2$.  A normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$ would have a peak density of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ here so we can use a Central Limit Theorem argument to suggest $\sqrt{\pi n}\, p_n \to 1$

Here are some values:

```
        n      p_n     1/sqrt(pi n)                 
        1 0.5000000000 0.5641895835
       10 0.1761970520 0.1784124116
      100 0.0563484790 0.0564189584
     1000 0.0178390111 0.0178412412
    10000 0.0056418253 0.0056418958
   100000 0.0017841219 0.0017841241
  1000000 0.0005641895 0.0005641896
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and thanks for including some values. It seems so counterintuitive at first that the probability goes to zeor but it helped me to just look at some values in addition to the "formal" reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

To see why the limiting probability is zero, consider that as $n$ becomes extremely large, the random variable $$Z = \frac{X - 2np}{\sqrt{2np(1-p)}} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$$ where $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(2n, p = 0.5).$$  That is to say, $Z$ is approximately standard normal, with the approximation improving as $n$ increases.  Then with continuity correction, $$\Pr[X = n] = \Pr[n - 1/2 \le X \le n + 1/2] = \Pr\left[-\sqrt{2/n} \le \frac{X - n}{\sqrt{n/2}} \le \sqrt{2/n} \right] \approx \Pr\left[ |Z| \le \sqrt{2/n}\right].$$  As $n \to \infty$, it follows that $\Pr[X = n] \to 0$.

This should also illustrate on an intuitive level why the LLN is not violated:  the specific event $X = n$ becomes *less* likely simply because there are many more possible outcomes clustered around it.  In other words, if I toss a coin $2$ times, the probability of getting exactly $1$ head is actually quite large, but as I toss the coin $200$ times, the chance of getting exactly $100$ heads is naturally much smaller because you have many other possible outcomes in which a fair coin can give "close to" but not exactly $100$ heads.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. My intuition was pretty off on this one. Thanks!